# How do I get rid of "category" from my URL structure?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, urls, link-category

By default WP links to a category like this, mydomain.com/category/travel.  Having the word "category" appear in the URL seems unnecessary. I'd prefer have the link read mydomain.com/travel.

How can I remove "category" from the URL structure? I don't want to replace it with something else as I can do by entering a new Category Base under Settings/Permalinks. But instead eliminate the Category Base all together so that the category names follows the domain name as in mydomain.com/travel.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer. Its most appreciated.

Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many plugins take care of that. The one i prefer is [Yoast Wordpress SEO plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/), as it does a lot of good things to your blog in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin can remove the /category/ from the url scheme for categories or any other taxonomies

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-taxonomy-base/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something were to happen to that plugin or the URL the answer would become useless.